# First attempt at a rebus

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, rebus

See if you can decipher this image:

[image: this rebus will bug you]

Comment: Ha ha ha, I like the image description!

Comment: Is that a pen in the right hand, or is that is that giving away too much to answer?

Comment: @Hawkeye:  it's a shuttle. :)

Comment: Ah... this has entered into an area I was totally and completely oblivious until I just looked it up. See, I started looking for the wings and cockpit. We all have our own rocks we live under I suppose. =D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the answer

> two tatting = tattoo?

Comment: Yup, you got it!  {applause] :)

Comment: @Wordster No check mark for me? :) (The tick under the downvote/ upvote button)

Comment: I'm slow, @Kevorobin, sorry! {tail between legs}